# Does the new Yammer API allow for embedding without an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, yammer

I embedded Yammer without using their JS SDK last year without an iframe so I could style the elements.

But now it doesn't work, so I've followed the guide at https://developer.yammer.com/upgrading-to-the-new-yammer-js-sdk/ adding the new script tag with my client app id and it seems to connect, but the container is still creating a iframe.

Is there still a way to embed the a feed without using an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

No, to embed a specific feed, group, or topic, you will have to use the iframe. Otherwise you will have to recreate the message posting, commenting/replying yammer view using their API's (this will bypass having to use the iframe but it will be difficult because of the rate limits on each service call.